# Сравнение 2-ух списков в python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, имеется два списка

```
    Ans = ['red','blue','green','white']
    Word = ['red','white']
```

Нужно сравнить два списка и совпадающие элементы вывести в отдельный список,скажем, result. Такой вопрос уже был, но я никак не могу понять как одинаковые элементы вывести.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Compare lists to find common elements in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13710517/4279)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Все таки Python динамичен и выразителен. Этого у него не отнять.

Там некоторые [логические и арифметические операторы перегружены для множеств](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference).

Вот Ваш однострочник:

```
result=list(set(Ans) & set(Word))
```

Это даст пересечение обоих списков:

```
['red', 'white']
```

Если нужен список уникальных элементов в объединении двух списков:

```
['red', 'white', 'green', 'blue']

result = list(set(Ans + Word))
```

Симметричная разность:

```
['green','blue']

result=list(set(Ans) ^ set(Word))
```

Обычная разность(Множество из `Ans` не входящее в `Word`):

```
['green','blue']

result=list(set(Ans) - set(Word))
```

Вариант, сохраняющий порядок с меньшим количеством конверсий типов:

```
sbuf = set(Word)
result = [x for x in Ans if x in sbuf)]
```

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, принял.

Comment: @ламер: Для поддержки повторяющихся значений можно `collections.Counter` вместо `set` использовать. Нужно быть осторожно с выражениями типа: `x in set(Word)` оно создаёт множество заново для каждого элемента (можно просто вывести создание множества из цикла). В последнем выражении `result` может дубликаты содержать и сам результат не  симметричен. Нет никакой необходимости преобразовывать `set()` в `list()` обратно: порядок и повторные элементы уже потеряны: `result = set(Ans).intersection(Word)` (здесь также не нужно второе множество создавать). Для полноты хэширование стоит упомянуть.

Answer (score 10):

Может быть, через генератор списков:

```
Res = [x for x in Ans if x in Word]
```

Comment: Ценное замечание, плюсанул и добавил в исправленном виде с конверсией в множество в ответ.

Comment: @igumnov: добавление вызова `set()` прямо внутрь выражения -- вредно здесь. Объяснить?

Comment: @jfs Оно что каждую итерацию его(`set(Word)`) будет вычислять? Тогда лучше в отдельный буфер да.

Comment: Стоит учитывать, что для списков Ans = [1,4,5,2,1] и Word = [1,4,5,2,111] вернет [1, 4, 5, 2, 1].