# Django filter для поиска пересечения двух списков

Tags: python, django, filter, queryset

В моделе есть поле со строковыми значениями, разделенными запятыми и есть список, с которым надо сравнить эти значения. Что-то вроде этого

```
all = Post.objects.filter(cities__in=citylst)
```

Как можно такое реализовать - как изменить форматы полей и как отфильтровать потом записи, где есть пересечение их списков с заданными списком?

Comment: Для поиска пересечений списков обычно списки переводят в сеты, вот пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427942/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-2-%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-python

Comment: А как перевести поле в сет в процессе фильтрации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постарался максимально приблизить свой ответ к вашему вопросу, джанги рядом нет.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,par1):
        self.b = par1

# список с которым сравниваем
list2 = ['2','4']

#Подготавливаем второй set для поиска пересечений
set2 = set(list2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #В all два объекта у которых есть строковое поле "b" разделенное запятыми
    all = A('1, 2, 3, 4, 5'), A('1, 2')

    for obj in all:
        #Подготавливаем первый set для поиска пересечений
        set1 = set(obj.b)

        #Находим пересечения'
        delta_set = set1 & set2
        print(delta_set)
```