# Сравнение элементов в разных списках

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции

Eсть 2 списка A и B.
Нужно чтобы каждый элемент из списка A искал соответствия в списке B,
и итого чтобы вывел несоответствия из списка A.

Comment: [Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+сравнение+списков) в различных вариациях уже неоднократно поднимался (в [частности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427942/Сравнение-2-ух-списков-в-python)).

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что считать несоответствием. Отсутствие элемента с таким-же значением в списке `b`, или неравенство элементов `a[i]` и `b[i]` Ну это так, на всякий случай.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'red', 'white']
b = ['red', 1, 7, 8]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x not in b, a)))
print([x for x in a if x not in b])
```

Comment: Мб, еще добавить этот аналог `print([x for x in a if x not in b])`?

Comment: @gil9red пожалуй стоит)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться особенностью множества `set`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'red', 'white']
b = ['red', 1, 7, 8]

d = list(set(a) - set(b))
print(d)  # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'white']

# Если не критично, что будет множество
d = set(a) - set(b)
print(d)  # {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'white'}
```

Comment: А если `a = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 'red', 'white']`? Поэтому лучшее решение - это ваше же list comprehension в ответе @Twiss

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'red', 'white']
b = ['red', 1, 7, 8]
print(set(a).difference(set(b)))
```

Так будет быстрее работать.

Comment: Быстрее, но неправильно. Если в исходом списке не только уникальные элементы, то ваше решение будет работать неверно. Поэтому в принципе, не смотря на свою привлекательность, варианты с множествами здесь не проходят.

Comment: @strawdog а почему не правильно? как я понял задача как раз из мира "множеств"?

Comment: мне кажется, потому что так в вопросе написано: *каждый элемент из списка A*.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сохранить порядок следования элементов, в варианте с множествами, то можно так:

```
a = [9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'red', 'white']
b = ['red', 1, 7, 8]
print(set(a).difference(set(b)))
print(sorted(set(a).difference(set(b)), key=lambda s: a.index(s)))

# {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'white', 9}
# [9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'white']
```

> к тому-же при сортировке, результат будет списком
>
> ***вариант с множествами, подойдет только в том случае, если достаточно возвратить множество элементов (результат будет содержать только уникальные значения), иначе, вариант с `filter` или генератором `not in` будет лучшим решением***

Comment: А зачем усложнять `key=lambda s: a.index(s)`?

Comment: @gil9red, "Если нужно сохранить порядок следования элементов". Ибо если возвращать множество, порядок следования элементов будет рандомным.

Comment: Логично, тогда, думаю лучше про сохранение порядка элементов указывать перед самой строкой :) Кст, заметили, что у моего ответа порядок элементов для `set` остался таким же? Помнится прочитал что с какой-то версии питона (у меня 3.6.5) сделано сохранение порядка для словарей и множеств

Comment: @gil9red, нет не заметил, добавьте, к примеру, 9 в начало списка `a` и убедитесь что не сохраняет

Comment: И вправда... дизинформировал... неловко получилось :)

Comment: @gil9red, "да пустяки, дело-то житейское" ))) имхо вариант с `filter` от @Twiss, заслуживает зеленой галки )))

Comment: @gil9red твой вариант самый кашерный, если речь о пересечении множеств)